# Move big amount of data to Elasticseach-hadoop efficiently

Tags: hadoop, twitter, elasticsearch, persistence, flume

I'm using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and a pool of workers to download tweets from Twitter and process them. I have also an instance of [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) over Hadoop. What I need is to move every tweet collected to that instance but as I'm working with a lot of data I'm not sure how to do this.

How can I move the data to Elasticsearch? Would be too much to make an insertion per tweet received? Is it [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) suitable for this? My main concern is avoid bottlenecks in the platform. Actually, I'm not using Flume right now to fetch the tweets because I need multiple agents with different keywords and update that keywords dynamically every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for indexing your Tweets into Elasticsearch given what you've exposed about your architecture. Three main options that I would consider:

- Use can use the Elasticsearch RabbitMQ River: This will automatically
  index all of the contents of a RabbitMQ queue into ES. Link is here:
  https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-rabbitmq/blob/master/README.md

  Note that their example is of indexing tweets routed thru RabbitMQ
  into ES so it seems to fit your model well. You may want to read up on ES Rivers: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/
- Use Logstash to pull from RabbitMQ and load into Elasticsearch:
  http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/rabbitmq and
  http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch
- Roll your own index interface via the REST API: Documentation and
  example here:
  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html
  Note that the example is for loading tweets too. It also supports bulk inserts via the api if you are concerned about the performance hit of indexing 1 tweet at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnPetrone. I'm not moving tweets through RabbitMQ. I'm only using it to deliver tasks (keywords and some more info) to the workers. River could fit, but I was thinking in a way to send a group of tweets to elastic (maybe also Hadoop). I know that elastic supports bulk operations but as I was reading about Flume I thought that could fit here as I could have multiple collectors with two sinks (elastic and hdfs). I think that I should read a bit more about this and about your three options.

Comment: So where is the data going now? Keep in mind that Flume, like Logstash, basically collects, processes and stores data (usually log files) - so if you want to assess the best way to index data into Elasticsearch I'd start with where is it today?

Comment: yeah, you are right. The data is in each worker. I download like 2000 json files per task in each worker and I have to move all to Elasticsearch/Hadoop.